# Implementing Monad.replicateM

Tags: scala, monads

Continuing on [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/)'s exercises, I'm trying to implement:

> def sequence[A](n: Int, ma: F[A]): F[List[A]]

Except for traverse, replicateOnce and replicateM, which I wrote, author is @pchiusano **EDIT** (spelled name incorrectly, sorry)

```
    trait Monad[F[_]] extends Functor[F] {
        def unit[A](a: => A): F[A]
        def flatMap[A,B](ma: F[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[B]

    def map[A,B](ma: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B] = 
        flatMap(ma)(a => unit(f(a)))
    def map2[A, B, C](ma: F[A], mb: F[B])(f: (A,B) => C): F[C] = 
        flatMap(ma)(a => map(mb)(b => f(a, b)))

    // Exercise 3: implement sequence() and traverse
    // official answer from @pchiusano
    def sequence[A](lma: List[F[A]]): F[List[A]] = 
        lma.foldRight(unit(List[A]()))((ma, mla) => map2(ma, mla)(_ :: _))

    def traverse[A, B](la: List[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[List[B]] =
        la.foldRight(unit(List[B]()))((ma, mla) => map2(f(ma), mla)(_ :: _))

    def replicateOnce[A](ma: F[A]): F[List[A]] = {
        map(ma)(x => List(x))
    }
```

For `replicateM`, I'm getting a compile-time error, **error: overloaded method value fill with alternatives**.

```
    // Exercise 4: implement replicateM
    def replicateM[A](n: Int, ma: F[A]): F[List[A]] = {
        sequence(List.fill(n, ma))
    }
}
```

Please point me in the right direction as I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `List.fill` incorrectly, it's a partially applied function so you need to first apply `n` and then `ma`:

```
   def replicateM[A](n: Int, ma: F[A]): F[List[A]] = {
        sequence(List.fill(n)(ma)) //note that the comma is removed
    }
```

Comment: Noah, could you please tell me the expected output of `streamMonad.replicateM(2, Stream("hello", "world")`? I got `Stream(List(hello, hello), List(hello, world), List(world, hello), List(world, world))`, but I don't know if it's right.

Comment: That output is correct. You should look through the impl of sequence and step through it element by element to understand why it's correct https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/monads/Monad.scala#L34